# Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.IndexDistance?' (aka 'Optional<Int>') and 'Int'

Tags: swift

in Swift 4 I'm trying to compare the length of the text of an UITextField  with a minimum length:

```
if textFieldPassword.text?.count >= 8 {        
}
```

but i'm getting the error

```
Binary operator '>=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'String.IndexDistance?' (aka 'Optional<Int>') and 'Int'
```

Ironically it works with

```
textFieldPassword.text?.count == 8
```

Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The reason is that `Equatable` works with optionals and `Comparable` does not. You have to unwrap the optional.

A suitable and safe solution is to optional bind the `text` property:

```
if let password = textFieldPassword.text, password.count >= 8 { ... }
```