# How to get an Int from a string.index?

Tags: swift, xcode, cocoa

swift 4.1, xcode 9.3, cocoa App

How to get an Int from string.index to use with other property number?

```
@IBOutlet weak var inputFromTextField: NSTextField!
@IBAction func button(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let temporaryHolder = inputFromTextField.stringValue.characters
    for input in temporaryHolder {
        let distance = temporaryHolder.index(of: input)
        print(input)
        print(distance + 100)
}
```

error code:

> Binary operator '+' cannot be applied to operands of type
>   'String._CharacterView.Index?' (aka 'Optional< String.Index >') and
>   'Int'

Comment: see this may be help with you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47485680/binary-operator-cannot-be-applied-to-operands-of-type-string-indexdistance

Comment: I believe their problem is about (aka 'Optional<Int>') and 'Int' [duplicate].
My problem is about  (aka 'Optional< String.Index >') and 'Int'.
So I don't think it can help. If it is just of optional, I can unwrap it, but this is string.index. So I can't.

Comment: This really is difficult hah? I have been working on it for 6 hours, and still couldn't find the solution. :3

Comment: no no is not difficult, follow the martins answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use `distance(from:to:)` to compute the (integer) distance
from a `String.Index` to the string's start position:

```
let str = "abab"
for char in str {
    if let idx = str.index(of: char) {
        let distance = str.distance(from: str.startIndex, to: idx)
        print(char, distance)
    }
}
```

But note that `index(of:)` returns the *first* index of the character
in the string, so the above code will print

```
a 0
b 1
a 0
b 1
```

If your intention is to get the running offset together with each character in the string then use `enumerated()`

```
for (distance, char) in str.enumerated() {
    print(char, distance)
}
```

This will print

```
a 0
b 1
a 2
b 3
```